# How can fixtures be replaced with factories using rails3-generators?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm trying to replace fixture generation with factories using rails3-generators:

https://github.com/indirect/rails3-generators#readme

The gem is included in my Gemfile and has been installed:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails3-generators', :group => :development
```

I added the following to application.rb:

```
# application.rb
config.generators do |g|
  g.stylesheets false
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl
end
```

Yet 'rails g model Insect' is still generating fixtures ('insects.yml'). Is this working for others using Rails 3.0.4 and rails3-generators 0.17.4?

'rails g' shows the new generators available (such as Authlogic and Koala), but 'rails g model' still lists fixtures and doesn't refer to factories.

What else should I add to get this to work? Thanks.

**Edit**: I ran the gem's test suite, which includes a test for this, and it passes. No clue why it doesn't work with my app.

**Edit2**: I tried again with a test project and get the same result: fixtures instead of factories. If anybody could confirm whether this works for them with Rails 3.0.4 and rails3-generators 0.17.4, that would be helpful too because it would imply that I'm doing something wrong with my projects.

**Edit3**: It works if I run 'rails g model Insect -r factory_girl'. I thought the generator configuration in application.rb was supposed to take care of that, so this seems to be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching around I found the following, which may help:

1. Try specifying a directory option for `factory_girl`'s factories:

   ```
   config.generators do |g|
     g.stylesheets false
     g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/factories" # or test/factories, as the case may be
   end
   ```
2. If you're using `Test::Unit`, try the following:

   ```
   config.generators do |g|
     g.stylesheets false
     g.test_framework  :test_unit, :fixture_replacement => :factory_girl
   end
   ```

In both cases you will still need the `rails3-generators` gem, although there is a push to get that functionality into `factory_girl_rails`.

[This Rails bug](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3937-gfixture_replacement-ignored) indicates that, at some point, the `g.fixture_replacement` code may not have worked right. Perhaps a test in 3.0.5 is in order. :)

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks Brandon, works now (OCD soothed). I did a bunch of searching before I posted but forgot to search the bug list. I am using Test::Unit (or MiniTest I guess, given 1.9.2) and #2 did the trick. I haven't tried 3.0.5 yet...

Answer (score 1):

A short update 9 years later:

instead of "factory_girl_rails" (which is deprecated now) use "factory_bot_rails".

Now, the factory gets created automagically:

> $ rails g model tester name:string
>
> Running via Spring preloader in process 31467
>
> ```
>  invoke  active_record
>
>  create    db/migrate/20200327152901_create_testers.rb
>
>  create    app/models/tester.rb
>
>  invoke    rspec
>
>  create      spec/models/tester_spec.rb
>
>  invoke      factory_bot
>
>  create        spec/factories/testers.rb
> ```

I use rails 5.2.4, but this should also work with rails 6.

Comment: Not sure but it seems like `factory_bot_rails` sets itself as the fixture replacement https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails/blob/b149856be340f919a49bab8d4389050dce422cbc/lib/factory_bot_rails/railtie.rb#L13-L15

Comment: Judging from the initializer call, it apparently does. I don't understand tho, to be honest. However I found [this list of fixture replacements](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_fixture_replacement.html) that may add a bit of value to the answer. Best